# Customized front end of odoo on the html

Tags: pycharm, odoo, odoo-16

I use odoo16 on pycharm, and I customized front-end using "Editor". By doing so, I want to ask where  html(.xml) file is stored after editing. I use odoo's E-commerce App.
Thank you!

I want to edit front end  of E-Commerce on the html (.xml) file of Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly. You *cant* find the html (xhtml in odoos case) file.

Theres 2 ways depending on what you wanna do :

#### Frontend Views

Under "**Technical**" > "**Views**" you find views that appear in the frontend. In most odoo versions, "Web.Layout" is the main view for the Website.

[image]

[image]

#### Backend Views

If you want to edit somehthing in a backend view. You can go on "get view" by clicking the on the **bug symbole** *(only in debug mode)* if you are trying to edit or find a backend view. (You have to navigate to the page you want t o change first )

[image]

### Edit Page

If none of these approaches are what youre looking for, I have one last option:

1. Navigate to the website
2. Klick on "Pages" and then "Configure Pages" (Titles may vary for each language, mines german i mightve translated incorrectly)
   [image]

The cou can click on the little Buf-Symbol on the right:
[image]

aaaand this is what i tlooks like
[image]

Hope it helps :) If it does, dont forgett to upvote <3